# How to add to a set in pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to run this code (some important part of the code is here):

```
Master = AbstractModel()
Master.intIndices = Set(initialize=INTVARS)
Master.constraintSet = Set(initialize=CONS)
Master.conIndices = Set(initialize=CONVARS)
Master.intPartList = Set()

Master.dualVarSet = Master.constraintSet * Master.intPartList

Master.theta = Var(domain=Reals, bounds = (None, None))
Master.intVars = Var(Master.intIndices, domain=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, 10))
Master.dualVars = Var(Master.dualVarSet, domain=Reals, bounds = (None, None))
max_iters = 1000
opt = SolverFactory("couenne")
for i in range(max_iters):
    Master.intPartList.add(i)
```

but it shows me this error on the last line:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot access add on AbstractOrderedSimpleSet 'intPartList' before it has been constructed (initialized).
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It appears you are initializing your sets from data....  So why don't you make this a pyomo `ConcreteModel` and initialize `Master.intPartList` like you are doing for the others?

Comment: It should be abstractModel. intPartList should be an empty set at first and during the iterations, I need to add more items to that set. The code that I provided is not the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `Master.intPartList` with any data, so you can't update it like that.  However, if you make your model a concrete model, and supply an initialization for your set you can...

```
In [11]: from pyomo.environ import *                                            

In [12]: m2 = ConcreteModel()                                                   

In [13]: m2.X = Set(initialize=[1,])                                            

In [14]: m2.X.add(2)                                                            
Out[14]: 1

In [15]: m2.X.pprint()                                                          
X : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
    Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
    None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {1, 2}

In [16]:
```

Comment: The thing is I cannot use `concreteModel` since I am changing the number of indices in one set of the master object. It means that in each iteration I am trying to solve one different MINLP. BTW, I fixed the issue, I will post it here.

Comment: I fixed the issue. The issue was that we were trying to change an object of the master before creating an instance which is not possible in the abstractModel. The quick way to fix it was to create a temporary python list and initialize the master object with that list and change the python list in each iteration. In summary, changing from:

Comment: ```Master.intPartList = Set()
for i in range(max_iters):
  Master.intPartList.add(i)
  instance = Master.create_instance()```
to:
```listTemp = []
Master.intPartList = Set(initialize=listTemp)
for i in range(max_iters):
  listTemp.append(i)
  instance = Master.create_instance()```